# nextLink in an Graph Api response not Absolute Uri

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

We are calling the graph api to get the users in our Azure **B2C** AD using this url

```
https://graph.windows.net/TENANTNAME.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6&$top=10&$select=objectId,userType,displayName,signInNames,createdDateTime&$filter=userType%20eq%20'Member'
```

*Note, the page size of 10 is deliberately small whilst I am writing this paging code*

The docs say that if there is more data to pull there will be a nextLink property in the response and that if it is present that uri should be used to get the next page of data. We do see a nextLink to be more exact it is `odata.nextLink` however the value is **not** usable as a uri for the next request.

Here is an example

```
directoryObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User?$select=objectId,userType,displayName,signInNames,createdDateTime&$filter=userType%20eq%20'Member'&$skiptoken=X'010001000000030000005903BF45BBE7EA4CB7378BD076AD388026EC6A89C7479240A83DE15C99D42A0C4B7E5E4C707FB448B45655AED90920FA6D7126F4D8990'
```

*Note, the skiptoken value as been shortened*

I can parse that nextLink and assemble a uri for the next page but that seems like a stupid idea as the value of nextLink should be opaque to me.

Is it because we are calling a B2C tenant?

Is there an agreed approach for parsing that link?

Comment: Hi, may I know if the answer provided below can meet your requirements ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem caused by design, Azure AD graph api just provide this kind of nextlink. Actually, Microsoft is recommending to use **Microsoft Graph** in place of the **Azure Active Directory Graph API** in order to access Azure AD’s resources. So you can use Microsoft graph api "[list users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)" to get the users in your AD, and it will show the absolute uri for the next link.

[image]

Comment: Whats the equivalent MS Graph Api call? I cannot see how I wouldpoint the call at a specific B2C tenant. The other thing I am thinking is if the AzureAd api is no longer being developed it means the nextLink is "stable" so I could invest in just parsing it knowing that it won't be changed.

Comment: Hi @PatLong-MunkiiYebee The equivalent MS Graph api is [list users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) which I mentioned in my answer.